# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null (Detailed)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Have searched a ton, can't find a solution. Am making a chrome extension. Here is what I have:

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "T",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Stuff"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});


});
```

content_script.js:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('DERIVED_SSTSNAV_PERSON_NAME'));
document.getElementById('DERIVED_SSTSNAV_PERSON_NAME').textContent = "test";
```

"Copy Element" off the page I'm working with:

```
<span class="PALEVEL0PRIMARY" id="DERIVED_SSTSNAV_PERSON_NAME">John Smith</span>
```

So, when I type both of those content_script.js ^ lines of code into console, I get what I want. I first get the whole <\span class...span>. Then .textContent spits out "John Smith." Fine and dandy.

The second I throw run my chrome script with the. exact. same. lines of code, I get "null" instead of <\span class...span> and then trying to access the .textContent throws me the error in my title.

What the heck? Seriously. I've spent hours redoing my manifest and trying to get that to work, but I can edit the DOM on other pages, just not this one. Would love to chat and get some feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: The code is correct. There's something else that's causing error. Maybe you click your extension icon before the element appears on the page.

Comment: @wOxxOm If the code is correct, and it should be - I have edited elements by ID on other pages, maybe the element ID is changing (?) or like you say, it's running too quickly. Is there anything I can do to chase this issue down? I've waited to click the extension icon, but no dice. I've literally spent days trying to fix this and I'm new to Js so no clue.

Comment: I guess it's inside an iframe, in which case there are several methods depending on whether the iframe is from the same domain or not.